# How do I stop the duration of the scrollTop

Tags: jquery, angularjs, directive, scrolltop

The directive I have now works good enough so far, but not every page has the same height so I want to stop the duration when it is already at the bottom.

This is the code of the directive:

```
function (scope, elem, attrs) {
        $(document).on('contentchanged', '#mainText',  function () {
            $("html, body").animate({
                scrollTop: 0
            }, 0),
            $("html, body").animate({
                scrollTop: $(window).height()
            }, 4000);
        });
    }
```

So for example at the first page the view is at the bottom it can't go any lower and when I go to the next page that is a bit lower it continuous scrolling down.

My question is **how can I stop it scrolling ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.animate( properties [, duration] [, easing] [, complete] )
```

so you could do something like this:

```
.animate( 
    {scrollTop:'300px'},
    300,
    swing,
    function(){ 
       alert(animation complete! - your custom code here!); 
       } 
    )
```

here is the jQuery .animate function api page: http://api.jquery.com/animate/